# RepositoryFactory with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ninject

I'm working on web application (web form). I want to be able to change EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory to NHibernateRepositoryFactory in the future.

**IRepositoryFactory**

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory

{

IProductRepository GetProductRepository();

}
```

**ProductRepository**

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{

ExDbContext _db;


public ProductRepository(ExDbContext dbContext)
{

_db = dbContext;

}



public IList<Product> ListProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{

List<Product> productsByCategoryId = _db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductCategoryId == categoryId).ToList();

return productsByCategoryId;

}

}
```

And there is **EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory**.

```
class EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory:IRepositoryFactory

{

ExDbContext _db;

public EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory(ExDbContext dbContext)

{

_db = dbContext;

//

// TODO: Add constructor logic here

//

}

public IProductRepository GetProductRepository()

{

return new ProductRepository(_db);

}

}
```

How can i make easy for changing this in future ? I want use ninject for access EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory but I'm stuck. Is there any example for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck? You have a single interface with one method that is easily mocked. What you asked for should be possible with what you've done.

Comment: @Atoms i cleared some methods for looking easy. Thats because single interface with one method. I asked a way for changing Factory class easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will add Ninject to your web application, fix your repository classes and add some Ninject modules to configure dependency injection:

1. **Install Ninject.** You can do this easily using the Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Ninject.Web -dependencyVersion Highest`
2. **Remove your RepositoryFactory.** Delete `IRepositoryFactory` and `EntityFrameworkRepositoryFactory`. You don't need them. Ninject will create a Repository and provide the dependencies as soon as your application asks for them. You need factories only to have better control of an object's lifetime.
3. **Fix the repository.** Let's make things more conventional and use an `IEnumerable<Product>` to return a read-only collection of products as result of our query. We also use `Get` as a prefix, as most repository patterns do:

   ```
   public interface IProductRepository 
   {
       IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId);
   }

   class EfProductRepository : IProductRepository
   {
       private readonly ExDbContext db;

       public EfProductRepository(ExDbContext dbContext)
       {
           this.db = dbContext;
       }

       public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId)
       {
           var productsByCategoryId = this.db
               .Products
               .Where(x => x.ProductCategoryId == categoryId)
               .ToArray();

           return productsByCategoryId;
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Create a Ninject module.** We need to bind our repository implementation to its interface. The Entity Framework `DbContext` uses the "Unit of Work" pattern, so we also need to make sure that our entity context instances are going to be disposed as soon as a request ends. We could do this using a context factory and the `using` directive, but we can also use the "Request Scope" of Ninject as it's easier:

   ```
   public class EfRepositoryModule : NinjectModule
   {
       public override void Load()
       {
           this.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EfProductRepository>();
           this.Bind<ExDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
       }
   }
   ```

   At first, we bind `IProductRepository` to our concrete implementation. Thereby, whenever a component needs a product repository, Ninject will create an instance of `EfProductRepository` and use that.

   Then we tell Ninject to bind `ExDbContext` to itself and use the request scope. All dependencies on `ExDbContext` will be served by one single instance of this class during a request, and this instance is going to be disposed when the request ends.
5. **Load the module.** In `App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs` update the following method:

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       kernel.Load<EfRepositoryModule>();
   }
   ```
6. **Add dependencies to your pages.** In every page where you need to show products, add the following property:

   ```
   [Inject]
   public IProductRepository ProductRepository { get; set; }
   ```

   We need to use property injection or method injection here, because Web Pages doesn't support constructor injection (which should usually be favored). The `Inject` attribute tells Ninject that we have a dependency here that we want to be injected.
7. **Add a module for NHibernate later on.**

   ```
   public class NHibernateRepositoryModule : NinjectModule
   {
       public override void Load()
       {
           this.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<NHibernateProductRepository>();
           // Bind whatever else you need when working with NHibernate
       }
   }

   // NinjectWebCommon
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       kernel.Load<EfRepositoryModule>();
   }
   ```